# URL rewrite is producing 404

Tags: iis, regex, arr

I'm trying to rewrite **office.domain.com/app1** requests to **server3:81** using the rule below, but I'm getting a 404. I can browse to **server3:81** just fine.

The Failed Request Tracing logs are available [here](http://1drv.ms/1mSEnkJ), but they don't seem to reveal much.

I've also tried `url="http://server3:81/{R:0}"` and `url="http://server3:81/{R:1}"` (not sure why/what the difference is), but both produce the same result (404).

What am I doing wrong in my rule? (Warning: I'm pretty unhandy with RegEx just yet, but I'll do my best to understand your answer. I may have to ask for clarification.)

---

```
<rule name="App1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^app1" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://server3:81/" />
</rule>
```